# http server Websocket and serving a static page

Tags: go

Consider the following sample

```
import (
    "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type MessageReceived struct {
    Name  string
    Nbmsg int
}

func Echo(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    msg := new(MessageReceived)
    for {
        websocket.JSON.Receive(ws, &msg)
        fmt.Printf("Received message: %+v\n", msg)
        if err := websocket.JSON.Send(ws, msg); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Can't send echo")
            break
        }
        //os.Exit(0)
    }
}

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Fatal error: %s\n", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/s", websocket.Handler(Echo))
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("web"))
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8081",fs)
    checkError(err)
}
```

The page and static files gets served but when but i try to connect to the websocket from javascript i get

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8081/s' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

The only way i could make it work is by serving static files from a different go application server and serving the websocket also from a separate server application using 2 different ports on the local host, what am i missing in the above sample? how could i serve files and the websocket from the same server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're assigning the `websocket.Handler` to the `DefaultServeMux`, but only using the `FileServer` handler in your `ListenAndServe` call.

Add the FileServer handler to the DefaultServe mux too, with some non-conflicting prefix:

```
func main() {
    http.Handle("/s", websocket.Handler(Echo))
    http.Handle("/f", http.FileServer(http.Dir("web"))
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
    checkError(err)
}
```